# EF4 and UnitOfWork - How to make custom properties work

Tags: entity-framework, unit-of-work

Say I have:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ARepository
{
    private SomeContext _context;
    public ARepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _context = unitOfWork;
    }
    public A GetAById(int aId)
    {
        return _context.A.Where(o => o.Id == aId).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get ; set; } //enum with NEW and OLD values
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }
}


public class BRepository
{
    private SomeContext _context;
    public BRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
       _context = unitOfWork;
    }
    public B GetBById(int bId)
    {
        return _context.B.Where(o => o.Id == bId).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And I'm working with Entity Framework (4.1 code first).

How would I implement for example a custom property in A class like:

```
//returns the total of all B objects in the context where the category is NEW
public int NewBTotals
{
}
```

And not having to create a context?

Hopefully my question is clear enough, if not please let me know and I'll try to be more descriptive of what I want to achieve (ran out of time).

Comment: Your code seems a bit incomplete, like your `Category` property is either missing it's type or its name.  And I'm not sure if there's a relationship between `A` and `B`, but I'm going to assume that `A` has a collection or relationship to B.  In either case, I would suggest that `GetNewBTotals` be implemented as an extension method rather than a custom property (the name actually implies its a method).

Comment: Basically due to bad DB design that I can't modify, A for instance has relationships with B through a column called "Source_reference". However B also could refer to X, Y or Z. And to find out which parent it depends on, we should look for a "Source" column. If I use extension methods I'll have to pass on the context somehow and this somehow I'm not sure of what would be the best approach.

Comment: What do you want to sum? Your comment says "total of all B objects *in the context*". But then you must have a context, why don't you want to create one? That sounds weird to sum over objects in the context because what's in the context depends on the kind of queries you did before or what you attached, etc.

Comment: The POCO entities in my point of view shouldn't directly be aware of contexts. So if I create a custom property that creates an instance of a context first I may create incompatibilities between the entity's own context and its custom property, which would have to be handled within the code. I know it may sound weird what I'm trying to achieve since I haven't used a real example but I wouldn't want to discuss the design but rather the best practice to solve the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that even by B not having a foreign key to A, I can create a navigation property from A to B and vice versa which kind of solves the problem on its own.